# Error trying to package Kivy app on OSX - "bridge.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, ios, macos, kivy

I'm trying to compile the Kivy sample pong code as an IOS app on my OSX machine.  I followed all the steps from http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html but it's not working, see example output below:

```
    kivy-ios/tools/create-xcode-project.sh test /Volumes/Kivy/examples/tutorials/pong
    -> Create /Users/vkuruthers/kivy-ios/app-test directory
    -> Copy templates
    cp: kivy-ios/tools/templates//bridge.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs... "...replace test with your project name". In your terminal command, try replacing the word 'test' with 'pong'.